# How far a window in Windows OS can go beyond the screen

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, window

This question sounds weird and dumb. But I still want to know how far a window in Windows OS can go beyond our computer screen. As we know, the mouse cursor will be blocked from exceeding the screen. But not for window. I have tried to verify this using Python 3.8 + Tkinter. The window stuck at certain point but I don't know how the limit was measured. Using pixel or what?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(999999999, 10)
root.mainloop()
```